# what is happening in this python code?

Tags: python, return, pyusb

The following snippet is from a [pyusb tutuorial](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#id10). It is being used to find all printers connected :

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import sys

class find_class(object):
    def __init__(self, class_):
        self._class = class_
    def __call__(self, device):
        # first, let's check the device
        if device.bDeviceClass == self._class:
            return True
        # ok, transverse all devices to find an
        # interface that matches our class
        for cfg in device:
            # find_descriptor: what's it?
            intf = usb.util.find_descriptor(
                                    cfg,
                                    bInterfaceClass=self._class
                                )
            if intf is not None:
                return True

        return False

printers = usb.core.find(find_all=1, custom_match=find_all(7))
```

This class seems to have multiple points where it returns a boolean value. How many returns are being sent?

Also I couldn't understand how this code searches all printers connected to the system.
Things in this code that escape me are:

- Is `device` a list/tuple? If yes, how does this code check all the devices by executing `if device.bDeviceClass == self._class:` just once?
- what is happening in this line: `self._class = class_`
- why is the class `find_class` never instantiated in `printers = usb.core.find(find_all=1, custom_match=find_all(7))`

  If you have worked on pyusb/any usb program, please tell me how.

Comment: +1 :) looks pretty clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is device a list/tuple?

`device` is a [`usb.core.Device`](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/usb/core.py#L457). Iterating over it [yields configurations](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/usb/core.py#L767).

> If yes, how does this code check all the devices by executing `if device.bDeviceClass == self._class:` just once?

It doesn't. You missed the part that says "So, to really find all printers connected to the system, we would need to transverse all configurations, and then all interfaces and check if one of the interfaces has its bInterfaceClass field equal to 7.".

> what is happening in this line: `self._class = class`_

Exactly what it says. It's binding the object in that argument to that attribute. For later use.

> why is the class find_class never instantiated in `printers = usb.core.find(find_all=1, custom_match=find_all(7))`

Because someone had a thinko. That last part should be `...=find_class(7)`.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about the multiple returns?

Comment: What about them? You can use `return` as many times as you like.

Comment: Well, about the returns, the code seems to return a boolean at multiple points and then ultimately returns `False`. Doesn't the final `False` return negate the other returns?

Comment: You can't "negate" other returns. You only return once.

Comment: Yea i get that but what I am trying to say is what is the significance of those `return True` commands in this case?The author finally sends `False` at the end of the method

Comment: Once a `return` statement is reached, the function stops being executed and control returns to the previous point in the call stack. What appears after the `return` statement never runs.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is the class `find_class` never instantiated in `printers = usb.core.find(find_all=1, custom_match=find_all(7))`**

In the tutorial you link to you’ll see that it’s a typo. The next line in the tutorial uses correctly `custom_match=find_class(7)`.

**What is happening in this line: `self._class = class_`**

In the example here it sets `self._class = 7`. (Coming from the line `find_class(7)`.) The reason not to use `self.class = class` is that “class” is a reserved word and would provoke a syntax error. Maybe this would be nicer:

```
class find_class(object):
    def __init__(self, class_nr):
        self.class_nr = class_nr
```

**Also I couldn't understand how this code searches all printers connected to the system.**

As mentioned in the tutorial, `usb.core.find()` returns the first device found, unless you pass a true value to the `find_all` argument. – It’s not the code you see that searches for all devices, it’s `usb.core.find()` which does. – It also answers the next question:

**Is `device` a list/tuple?**

No.

**This class seems to have multiple points where it returns a boolean value. How many returns are being sent?**

The `__call__()` is called for each device `usb.core.find()` finds. The device is passed in `device`. `__call__()` will return only once for each call (obviously). How many times it is called depends on the devices found in the system.

The loop you find in there is for a single device only! The custom search is happy (in this case) if the device is class 7 *or* any of it’s configurations has an interface with class 7.